# Can't see iphone inside iTunes in a windows 10 VM in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, itunes, iphone

I'm trying to restore my iPhone.  I don't have a windows or mac computer, just Ubuntu, so I'm running iTunes in a Windows 10 VM that I just started using VirtualBox.

When i plug the iphone in to the USB port, my host computer (Ubuntu) "notices", but it says it was unable to mount the phone.  (The phone shows as charging).

Inside the VM, iTunes does **not** notice that the phone has been plugged in - I was hoping it would pop up on iTunes list of devices.

Is there something I can change in the VirtualBox config so that the VM "notices" that a device (iphone, specifically) has been connected via USB?

Grateful for any advice, thanks.

EDIT - after a bit of googling I found some advice that I need to install the extpack (extension pack) for VirtualBox in order to enable USB support.  I did that, closed the windows VM, ticked the "Enable USB Support" in the config for the VM, and restarted the VM.   But, it still doesn't notice when I plug the iphone in.

Comment: Along the bottom of the VM are some icons, one should look like a USB connector.  If you right-click on it, it should bring up a window of USB devices connected to your computer.  Click your iPhone to pass it through to the VM.  (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-usb-in-virtualbox/)

Comment: @essjae ah...thanks.  Hmm, i'm hovering over that icon and it says "No USB devices attached".

Comment: This sounds like you have a connection issue with your phone, especially if the host can't mount it.  Maybe a new cable, or try a different USB port.

Comment: I basically gave up trying to do it via a VM and went in to work out of hours to use a windows 10 computer there.  But thanks anyway.